# gnuplot: use regular expressions to parse string

Tags: regex, string, parsing, gnuplot

Tell me PLZ how in the gnuplot script you can

1) parse a string and extract a number and a letter/string from it?

2) is it possible to use associative arrays so as not to use multi IF?

```
files = system(sprintf("dir /b \"%s*.csv\"", inputPath))

do for [name in files]{

    # MY TROUBLES IS HERE
    [value, typeID] = parse(name, "*[%d%s]*"); # pseudocode
    typesList = {"h": 3600, "m": 60, "s": 1};

    scale = value * typesList[typeID];
    # MY TROUBLES IS ABOVE

    myfunc(y) = y * scale

    outputName = substr(name, 0, strlen(name) - strlen(".csv"))

    inputFullPath = inputPath.name
    outputFullPath = outputPath.outputName.outputExt

    plot inputFullPath using 1:(myfunc($2)) with lines ls 1 notitle
}
```

In my case, I need to get the number of seconds from the file name of the form `...[d=17s]...`, `...[d=2m]...`, `...[d=15h]...` etc

In a more complicated case: `...[d = 2h7m31s]...` (this is a general case, it is unlikely to be useful to me, but it would be interesting to know how to resolve it)

Comment: `gnuplot` is not intended for parsing character strings, so you need to change approach. You can put this information at the beginning of your file (in seconds), read it, and then read the data skipping the first line. Or because judging by `dir` you are using Windows, you can download `grep` or `sed` utilities from GnuWin32 repo (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) and read the documentation how to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gnuplot does not support regular expressions, but you can write a function which extracts the times in seconds from your filename.
If your filename and timestamp have a strict format, e.g. like `"...[d=2h7m31s]..."` you could use the following code. Otherwise you have to adapt it accordingly.

1. First extract the `2h7m31s` part with `strstrt()`
2. parse it with `strptime()`
3. and make an integer out of it with `int()`

**Script:**

```
### parse special time string

NAME = "Filename[d=2h7m31s].csv"

TimeExtract(s) = int(strptime("%Hh%Mm%Ss",s[strstrt(s,'[d=')+3:strstrt(s,']')-1]))
    
print TimeExtract(NAME)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
7651
```

**Addition:**

the following code also covers other possibilities as long as the sequence is `...[d=..h..m..s]...`.

*Update:* (hopefully the final version)

The timeformat `%H` would wrap at 24 hours (actually, here it does at 100 h).
So, in order to get the correct time in seconds, the specifier should be `%tH`, `%tM` and `%tS` (check `help time_specifiers`). With this, you can also parse strange formats like `[d=100h100m100s]`.

**Script:**

```
### parse special time string
reset session

$Data <<EOD
abcd[d=31s]somethingelse.csv
efghi[d=7m]somethingelse.csv
jklmn[d=2h]somethingelse.csv
op[d=7m31s]somethingelse.csv
qr[d=2h31s]somethingelse.csv
uvw[d=2h7m]somethingelse.csv
xyz[d=2h7m31s]somethingelse.csv
aaa[d=100h100m100s]strangetime.csv
EOD

getTimeString(s) = s[strstrt(s,'[d=')+3:strstrt(s,']')-1]

getTimeFormat(s) = \
    (strstrt(getTimeString(s),'h') ? '%tHh' : '').\
    (strstrt(getTimeString(s),'m') ? '%tMm' : '').\
    (strstrt(getTimeString(s),'s') ? '%tSs' : '')

extractTime(s) = int(strptime(getTimeFormat(s),getTimeString(s)))

do for [i=1:|$Data|] {
    s = $Data[i]
    print sprintf("% 12s   %d",getTimeString(s),extractTime(s))
}
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
         31s   31
          7m   420
          2h   7200
       7m31s   451
       2h31s   7231
        2h7m   7620
     2h7m31s   7651
100h100m100s   366100
```

Comment: good! What to do, is the date of a non-strict format, as in the examples above?

Answer (score 1):

I came to your post by searching the same objective: grep a pattern in the middle of a file up to a space, to get a list string usable in gnuplot.

```
new_plan.txt:
blabla CIC1 blabla
blabla CIC2.2-prod blabla
blabla CIC1 blabla
etc.
```

^ File to parse ^

```
gnuplot> system("cat new_plan.txt| sed -n -E 's/^.*(CIC\\S*).*$/\\1/p' |sort |uniq")
```

Result:

```
CIC1 
CIC2.2-prod
```

The annoying thing is not-to forget to antislash the antislash \ because it is in a string so that gnuplot can call it with the system call.

I do not answer your title question, but your last comment:

> (this is a general case, it is unlikely to be useful to me, but it
> would be interesting to know how to resolve it)

Comment: Of course, you can always make system calls and use external tools to process your data or strings. This assumes that you have sed, awk or other tools installed, which might be true for Linux users, typically not the case for others.